# How to return different class object depending on some condition?

Tags: c#, .net, factory-pattern

I have method where I create class object depending on some condition and want to return only that object which satisfies the condition. In the return method I need to call that object's class method

I can do with `object`, `dynamic`, or `Tuple` but how can we do with reflection or some other method to return only one object?

```cs
public dynamic GetInvokeType(string id)
{
    log.Info("GetInvokeType(): " + id);

    if (id.ToLower() == "cm")
    {
        BCMSDashboardManager b = new BCMSDashboardManager();
        return b;

    }
    else
    {
        SIPManager s = new SIPManager();                
        return s;

    }
}
```

In the returned method, I will be calling its method based on the returned class object. So, I want to return only one object, not in `Tuple`, `object`, or `dynamic` type.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Surely, you understand that C# uses strong, static (compile-time) typing. Given your scenario, it seems likely that it's a mistake for the same method to return such disparate objects in the first place. Otherwise, they'd have a common base class, where that class has the method you want to call after the object is returned. And of course, that would work fine. Your code example is also confusing, because you return not the object itself, but just its associated `Type`. So, there's that.

Comment: This rather smells like a wrong understanding/implementation of the factory pattern. You should go over your design an check if your polymorphism/inheritance can be improved.

Comment: This is just a snippet of code. My ultimate intention is to return the class object based on condition.

Comment: Uaully Factory pattern need return "parent class" , like `interface` for example , a interface `ICar` , `RedCar : ICar`  , ` BlueCar : ICar`  CarFactory always return `ICar` , And Use CarFactory be simple to get a `ICar` without know how to make it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read a bit about [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#).

Shortly, you should do smth like this:

- Create common interface **IManager** for you manager (SIPManager, ...)
- some method which will return instance of class (which implements **IManager** interface)

  ```
  // Common interface with desired methods
  public interface IManager
  {
      void Manage();
  }
  public class BCMSDashboardManager : IManager
  {
      public void Manage()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("BCMSDashboardManager");
      }
  }
  public class SIPManager : IManager
  {
      public void Manage()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("SIPManager");
      }
  }
  ```

And now you could create factory method, which returns instances of specific class

```
public IManager GetInvokeType(string id)
{
    switch (id.ToUpperInvariant())
    {
        case "CM":
            return new BCMSDashboardManager();
        default:
            return new SIPManager();
    }
}
```